# Adding a Key Listener to ChipsInputEditText

Tags: android, android-layout

Using a normal EditText, adding a key listener provides the expected behavior when my application runs. However, adding a key listener to the ChipsInputEditText using the MaterialChipsInput library, does not produce the expected behavior. The onKey method from the key listener does seem to be called at all, none of the log statements are showing up in the console. The code is shown below:

```
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("compose message", "onKey called");
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)){
                Log.i("compose message", " onKey called");
                String userName = ((ChipsInputEditText) view).getText().toString();
                Constants.DATABASE.child("userlist").orderByValue().equalTo(userName)
                        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    Constants.DATABASE.child("users/"+dataSnapshot.getKey())
                                            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    HilarityUser hu = dataSnapshot.getValue(HilarityUser.class);
                                                    chipsInput.addChip(new HilarityUserChip(hu));
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                                            });
                                } else {
                                    //todo show toast
                                    return;
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Is there something I glossed over, or should I just make a fragment with an autocomplete TextView and a RecyclerView to show the chips?